# Why the coil on high tension wires

Tags: electricity, everyday-life

Today I saw some high tension wires of which some (the middle two) had some large coils wound on top of them as in the image, every 50 meters or so, over a few hundred meters. Does anyone know what those are for?

[image: coils]

Comment: I believe these are for vibration damping - but will look for some references before posting as an answer.

Comment: Vibration damping of towers is usually done with a Stockbridge damper, which looks quite different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockbridge_damper

Comment: These look more like a repair. Shunts that restore the conductivity in a line that was damaged. Hot spots can be detected by IR cameras during inspections.

Comment: Were they at regular/equal intervals and in pairs as shown?

Comment: "These look more like a repair." I was thinking the same thing. Maybe they are splices in the transmission line? I could see how they might not want to do a direct splice because the cables are under a lot of stress, and it might be difficult to satisfy the twin requirements of both (a) high strength and (b) high conductance across the splice with a single cable. So instead they use a short straight length of, say, steel cable to handle the high mechanical stress requirement at the splice, and then use some high conductivity cable of, say, copper to carry the electricity across the splice.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Where I saw them (maybe six or eight pairs) they came in pairs, always on the same two lines, and they were at approximately regular intervals.

Comment: [This](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167295/what-is-this-object-found-on-transmission-lines) might be a good place to ask. If you do, please let us know.

Comment: What country is this pic from?  Might help us narrow down the choice of engineering technology involved.

Comment: BTW, my original reaction was that these are in fact weak inductors, added to control the phase of the AC signal. I have no reason to claim that's the truth, tho.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It is from Spain, Barcelona area

Comment: I asked [electronics.stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194129/what-are-these-coils-on-transmission-lines).

Comment: We have an answer from @MarkoBuršič . It looks more like [Bird Flight Diverter](http://www.ecvv.com/product/4056002.html) than [spiral vibration damper](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ADSS-spiral-vibration-damper_567003625.html).

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks!  nothing to do with Maxwell's equations then!

Answer (score 1):

I was walking on the Rota Vicentina, SW Portugal, and saw the same thing. They are to protect migrating birds from the high voltage line. Check out 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ssrLFLwvdo